# Should I throw an unhandled when a custom Exception handler middleware?

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1

I have a custom middleware where I catch and log every exception, the part where I catch an unhandled exception looks like this:

```
catch (Exception exception)
{
    this.logger.LogError(exception);
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Unhandled").ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

But I'm wondering if besides logging I should throw, every blog I have seen just write the response but never throw, I dont know if I'm leaveing my API in a bad state and should throw so the load balancer creates a new container or is it OK to keep runing the same instance.